# $.ajax(): responseText is correct but error is reported. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to fetch some JSON data from my server like so:

```
var a = $.ajax({
    url: "data.json",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: null,
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("error");
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("success");
    }
});
```

When I do this, the `error` function is called (`error` is printed to the console).

Curiously, though, when I examine `a` I see that the correct response text has been returned.

`a`

```
readyState: 4
responseText: "contents of data.json!"
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
```

What's going on?  Why isn't the success callback firing if the request is succeeding?

Comment: Is the `responseText` valid JSON? You can check it with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: @ianpgall's answer is correct, but you should also note that there's an extra comma at the end of your options object (line 6).

Comment: Good point @harrison_m 34, but that doesnt seem to be an error in javascript, at least in newer browsers. Ive seen that break stuff in older versions of IE (maybe newer too). Make a simple webpage and test that out, there shouldnt be an error

Comment: @harrison_m   Thanks for catching that. I just edited that comma out of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because the specific value being returned isnt in the type that you specified. The response itself is a success (as you see by viewing the details of "a"), but that is not the only deciding factor for whether succes or error is executed. You specified json as the "dataType" (return type), but received a string. For testing, thats fine, but as you see, things wont run as expected. If you dont specify the dataType option, jQuery will attempt to determine the content type returned by looking at the mime type and the content of the response. Its an error when they dont match up (as in your case).

UPDATE:

I realized I rambled in my explanation above. Although you seemed to fix the problem, let me elaborate again.

There were several possibilities for errors to occur in your situation. The important thing to understand is that if you set "dataType", jQuery will attempt to parse the responseText with that type. If you do not set that option, it will guess and parse it accordingly (that means it will look at the MIME type) and parse it that way. If you specify the "dataType", the responseText needs to be in the format of JSON. So if you specify "json", but provide a string (in your case), jQuery parsing fails. If you don't specify the "dataType" and jQuery guesses, the responseText needs to match the MIME type. So you can't return a string when the MIME type is "application/json". When things don't match up, that's when errors occur.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Should that last sentence be "the returned string couldn't be parsed as JSON" ?

Comment: Thanks @ianpgall.  That solved it!  (I'd inserted dummy text in my question.  My actual string looked a lot more like JSON, but it had a few little quirks that make it fail the JSONLint test.)

Comment: @alex I don't know, but I updated my answer :) glad it could help the OP though, hopefully it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hunch, but is the content type being returned "application/json"?  My hunch is that the error is that JSON is expected back, but it is returning text/html (or some other content type) that is then not being parsed.